# Can't show an alert box JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I'm trying to make this alert appear but it doesn't seems to work, I've tried almost everything but nothing actually works.

I've tried taking out the variable of the alert and it works, but I need it to show the result of the multiplication.

Then I've tried just adding the variable in the alert box but It doesn't work, and I can't find where is the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>    
<title>Multiplication</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2> Ange 2 tal för att multiplicera</h2>
<table  border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Första Tal</th>
    <th>Andra Tal</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="disp_alert()" value="Multiplicera" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <script>


function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.value = myResult;    
}
    function disp_alert() {
        alert("Resultaten blir"+result.value);
    }

  </script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `result`, and thus `result.value` only exist inside the `calculate()` function. `disp_alert()` has no idea what `result` is.

Comment: I think you need to pass some value ! try this for your button : `onclick = "disp_alert(calculate())"`

Comment: result is your local variable.. its value destroys

Comment: Also, you don't have this element on page:  var result = document.getElementById('result'); Add HTML element you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to calculate when you click the button.

```js
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    return myBox1 * myBox2;
}

function disp_alert() {
    var product = calculate();
    alert(product);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2> Ange 2 tal för att multiplicera</h2>
<table  border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Första Tal</th>
    <th>Andra Tal</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="disp_alert()" value="Multiplicera" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I believe it would be better if he separated the concerns. Having a function doing multiple things is not a good thing.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess I could rename `disp_alert` to `calculate`

Comment: Even then it would be better if it was separated. Think about it .. You could calculate those values in a million ways, like you could display them in different ways.. In this case seems irrelevant because of how small the code actually is, but, in bigger amounts of code creating functions for specific tasks is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `result` only exists within the `calculate()` function.  You need to retrieve the value again in the `disp_alert()` function.

```
function disp_alert() {
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    alert("Resultaten blir"+result.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your button :

```
<td><input type="button" onclick="disp_alert(calculate())" value="Multiplicera" /></td>
```

Your `result` variable is in the scope of your function `calculate()` so `disp_alert()` does not know what `result` is.

```
var global_result; <---- this variable is accessible to all functions.

function calculate(){
 var result; <--- this is a local variable only accessible within this function
}

disp_alert(calculate()) <--- calculate innards become available to disp_alert
```

By putting the call off `calculate()` inside of `disp_alert()` that value becomes accessible.